# How to enable direct rendering for i915 driver?

Tags: drivers, opengl, i915

My `glxgears` works just fine, bit of slow though. When running on some python OpenGL [demo](http://pg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#glsl-shaders-and-programs), it crashes with

```
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  168 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  114
  Current serial number in output stream:  114
```

My OpenGL version and mesa goes as follows,

```
$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 Mesa 10.1.3)
```

Also, direct rendering is set to false. I would like to verify if it is the "direct rendering" that is causing the problem. But I didn't find a proper solutino on the web. Can anyone help me out?

--Edit--

```
$ lspci -knn | grep VGA -A3
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics [8086:1912] (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:06b9]
        Kernel driver in use: i915
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:a12f] (rev 31)
```

And segfault encountered with `vainfo`

```
$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 0.36.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_36
Segmetation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Did you have package `i965-va-driver` installed? Please add output of `lspci -knn | grep VGA -A3` and `vainfo` to your question.

Comment: @N0rbert It seems `i915` is installed and my graphics is shown `Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 256 bits)` under system information overview.